# MySql Replication Stored to Central Database

Tags: mysql, backup, replication

Hi I maybe looking with the wrong terminology.

But i have a situation where i need to replicate / copy data to a centralized database.

Shop1.dbshop - > Central.dbshop1

Shop2.dbshop - > Central.sbshop2

etc.

I managed to get a master-slave setup and working for one store but how do i add an additional slave connection to the central server, if this is even possible. Or do i have to completely go a different route.

I'm fairly new to the replication inside MySQL.

thanks in advance

Phoenix

Comment: What did you try? Single master/multiple slave setups are extremely common. Setup of each slave is always the same. The only catch in your setup seems that your database *and* table names are different on the master and slave. That may not be possible (DB is possible, table not AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check below mysql guide for adding server to existing replication

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-howto-additionalslaves.html

Comment: thanks for the response, i believe that this guide is for adding an additional slave to the existing set.

i need to have the shops which are in different locations replicating to a central db

for example 

uk(shop) to HQ(ukdb)
new york(shop) to HQ(nydb)

the databases do not need replicating across all, i would ideally like master-slave multiple times but all the slaves on one instance, if this is not possible i will have to do multiple instances on the slave server.

if i have got the wrong end of the stick i apologize.